# Multiple Windows or Tabs in React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

We are using *react-admin* for a back-office application.
We need to let user to open multiple tabs (similar to chrome tabs, but within the app) and navigate in each tab in different pages. So user can open new sessions without using the previous ones.

Is there a way to do it with react-admin?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can already use several tabs on the same admin with react-admin. Can you please explain what you've tried, and what problem you met?

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto Our goal is to load multiple inner tabs within the same chrome tab. Currently there is no inner support from React Admin as I understand.

Comment: That shouldn't pose any problem. You can instantiate several `<Admin>` components in a single app. Use material-ui tabs for the main layout. I suggest you give it a try and report here if you meet any issue.